# Is the Jacobson radical of a ring satisfying the descending chain condition on its two-sided ideals nilpotent?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Let $R$ be a ring with identity that satisfies the descending chain condition on its **two-sided ideals**. Is it true that the Jacobson radical $\text{Jac}(R)$ of $R$ is nilpotent?

Suppose $R$ is commutative, then $R$ is Artinian. So this result holds for commutative rings. But I have no idea for the non-commutative case. I tried some examples(e.g. the ring of endomorphisms of a vector space of countably infinite dimension) , but they all have zero Jacobson radical.

If it doesn't hold, is there a counterexample? Thanks.

Comment: One has $J^n=J^{n+1}$ for some $n$, so if $J$ is finitely generated, then $J^n=0$ by Nakayama’s Lemma.

Comment: One can immediately see that $J(R)^n=J(R)^{n+1}$ or some $n$ using the DCC. If $J(R)$ were finitely generated on either side as an $R$ module, Nakayama's lemma would create a contradiction if $J(R)$ is not nilpotent. So $J(R)$ must not be finitely generated... I've got examples in mind where $R$ is local with $J(R)$ idempotent, but none of them have the DCC on ideals.  Not sure of any good ways to get that for free.

Comment: @Andrew Hubery
 Thanks for your comment! Yes, I am more interested to know if there are any counterexamples when the $J(R)$ is not finitely generated.

Comment: @rschwieb Thanks! Can you tell me what is an example of a local ring R with $J(R)≠\{0\} $ idempotent? (Just curious :)

Comment: @Tin-SengCik For a field $k$, $R=k[x^{1/2},x^{1/4},x^{1/8},...]/(x)$ is a commutative, local ring whose maximal ideal is both nil and idempotent.  [DaRT entry](https://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/rings/ring/47/)

Comment: @rschwieb Thanks！